# Make use of ConverterParameter vs. using many converters

Tags: wpf, performance, valueconverter

I have 2 different `ProgressBars` with 2 different custom styles. In each of them, Color of the `ProgressBar` is Calculated based on `Maximum` and `Value` (with 2 different formulas).

I see that the type of the `ConverterParameter` in a converter is `String`.
Now I'm wondering should I write 2 different `MultiValueConverters` for each of them, or write a single `MultiValueConverter` with a `Parameter` and let the `Parameter` decide which formula should be executed.

These 2 `ProgressBars` are probably the bottle-neck of my MVVM's View, so I need to know which one is better in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write one converter - it makes no sense to have multiple converters for the same purpose.

Indicate which formula you want to use by using an enumeration - the value can be explicitly mentioned in the XAML.

If you want to bind external values in to your converter it will need to derive from DependencyObject and the properties will have to be dependency properties.